# Connect WinForms to SQL Server 2008 R2 from another computer

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008-r2

I know this question has been asked alot here. But I'm too tired right now to read lots of stuff. So here's the question : "Can my project register data to another PC's database ?". The other PC doesn't have any database installed on it, no Visual Studio, nothing. So image it like a formatted PC, which I use to test all my applications. So this PC is testing my application, and will insert data to my database through the internet. Is that possible ? Refer me somewhere please. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. When you're setting up your database connection string, you can specify a remote machine, but it will have to have some sort of RDMS installed and running on it--you can't open a connection to a server that isn't running.

Since there are plenty of different databases out there you could connect to, I sometimes go to http://www.connectionstrings.com/ to figure out how to put one together.